# How to change text "Your comment is awaiting moderation." wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show a custom message while comment status is on hold or pending for approval. `wp_set_comment_status($comment_object->comment_ID, 'hold');`
Currently it is showing the message "Your comment is awaiting moderation."

my current code is :

```
function new_comment_inserted($comment_id, $comment_object) {
    if ( get_post_type($comment_object->comment_post_ID) == 'product' ) {
        wp_set_comment_status($comment_object->comment_ID, 'hold');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment','new_comment_inserted', 99, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to code. Just only Install "[Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)", and change that text in "Core" section.

Comment: Was it usefull ?